Mutt Segmentation Fault with MX Linux 21.3 #129
New noob here. Using MX Linux, set up Mutt with gmail. Was initially successful. Emails and all. Then at some point when trying to use again, it stuck at 4% giving a segmentation fault. Using gdb it says:
Fetching message headers... 6202/132349 (4%)
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7c2ea5f in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtokyocabinet.so.9
(gdb) bt
#0 0x00007ffff7c2ea5f in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtokyocabinet.so.9
#1 0x00007ffff7c2fca8 in tcbdbput () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtokyocabinet.so.9
#2 0x000055555561e5da in ?? ()
#3 0x000055555561eded in ?? ()
#4 0x000055555562dfe3 in ?? ()
#5 0x000055555562bb1c in ?? ()
#6 0x000055555562893d in ?? ()
#7 0x00005555555b774e in ?? ()
#8 0x000055555556c3ea in ?? ()
#9 0x00007ffff795cd7a in __libc_start_main () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#10 0x000055555556d44a in ?? ()

What do I do?

Great debugging effort!
